# Product of Normal Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm trying to prove something regarding solvable groups, but I got stuck near the end with this problem: Let $K \unlhd H \leq G$ and $N \unlhd G$. I'm trying to prove that $NK \unlhd NH$. I've tried to do this through conjugation-invariance:
$$(nh)^{-1}n'k(nh) = h^{-1}n^{-1}n'knh$$
but got stuck. I'd really appreciate a clue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just continue:
$$ \begin{align} 
(nh)^{-1}n'k(nh) = h^{-1}n^{-1}n'knh & = h^{-1}n^{-1}n'h\cdot h^{-1}kh\cdot h^{-1}nh 
\\ &\in NKN
\end{align} $$
and as $N$ is normal, $KN=NK$ (because $kn=(knk^{-1})\cdot k$).